# How to handle GET parameter in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

I would like to get the url parameter and if url is defined wrongly by user, i need to send an error.

My url is: `localhost:8080/user?id=1`

If the url entered by the user is: `localhost:8080/use?id=1`, how do we handle it?

```
if (app.get("/user")) {
  app.get("/user",function(req,res,next){
    console.log('In');
  });
} else {
  console.log('something went wrong in url');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for an if/else statement. Simply list all of your paths, and add a default path at the end. If query does not match with any of your definitions, it will call the default path.

```
app.get("/user",function(req,res){
    res.send('called user');
});

... 

app.get("/*", function(req, res){
   res.send('wrong path');
});
```

Note that the order is important, if you put the `"/*"` at the top, it will dominate the others. So it has to be the last.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse **req.url** using *parse* function from **url** module:

Here is  [the example](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_message_url) from node.js documentation:

```
node> require('url').parse('/status?name=ryan')
{ href: '/status?name=ryan',
  search: '?name=ryan',
  query: 'name=ryan',
  pathname: '/status' }
```

Answer (score 0):

`app.get` is an event handler. The corresponding `callback` gets called only when a request matches that route. You don't need to specify an if statement for it. You need to do study a bit of javascript and how events/callbacks work. I think [this article](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) which looks decent.

Answer (score 0):

app.get is an event handler. **No need of the if condition.** 
I prefer you to change the url from

```
localhost:8080/user?id=1
```

To

```
localhost:8080/user/1
```

If the path ie: localhost:8080/user/1 is not defined then the freamwork automatically display message

> Cannot GET /user/1

```
app.get("/user/:id", function(req, res){
console.log('In userId = '+req.params.id);
}) ;
```

Note the **:id**, you can use this name to access the value in your code.If you have multiple variables in your url, for example

```
localhost:8080/user/1/damodaran
```

so your app.get will look like

```
app.get("/user/:id/:name", function(req, res){
console.log('In userId = '+req.params.id+' name:'++req.params.name);
}) ;
```

Check these links

[expressjs api](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

[Express app.get documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718962/express-app-get-documentation)