# Explain to Mean.io beginner how Mean.io sample package's authentication works

Tags: node.js, express, mean.io

I'm learning [mean.io](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) from [this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gOZCDuQ6xY#t=4m27s), which shows the example package (created by `mean package mymodule`. It is also described under "Packages" on the [docs](http://mean.io/#!/docs)). I would like help in understanding how the given authentication/authorization works.

The default sample package/module has a simple user authentication that on the client side

*myapp/packages/mymodule/public/views/index.html* contains:

```
    <li>
      <a href="mymodule/example/anyone">Server route that anyone can access</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="mymodule/example/auth">Server route that requires authentication</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="mymodule/example/admin">Server route that requires admin user</a>
    </li>
```

On the server side,

*myapp/packages/mymodule/server/routes/mymodule.js*, contains:

```
// The Package is past automatically as first parameter
module.exports = function(Mymodule, app, auth, database) {

  app.get('/mymodule/example/anyone', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Anyone can access this');
  });

  app.get('/mymodule/example/auth', auth.requiresLogin, function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Only authenticated users can access this');
  });

  app.get('/mymodule/example/admin', auth.requiresAdmin, function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Only users with Admin role can access this');
  });

  ...
};
```

The magic of the different authentication relies on the second argument of `app.get()` with [additional authentication callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718962/express-app-get-documentation): none, `auth.requiresLogin`, or `auth.requiresAdmin`.

This is the authentication magic (also on [github](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/access/server/config/authorization.js)):

*myapp/packages/access/server/config/authorization.js*:

```
/**
 * Generic require login routing middleware
 */
exports.requiresLogin = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.send(401, 'User is not authorized');
  }
  next();
};

/**
 * Generic require Admin routing middleware
 * Basic Role checking - future release with full permission system
 */
exports.requiresAdmin = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated() || !req.user.hasRole('admin')) {
    return res.send(401, 'User is not authorized');
  }
  next();
};
```

**QUESTION A: Why is it "exports.requiresLogin" and "exports.requiresAdmin" in the authorization.js instead of "somethingelse.requiresLogin" and "somethingelse.requiresAdmin"?**  Is this "exports" related to the *myapp/packages/access/server/config/passport.js*'s `exports`: `module.exports = function(passport) { ...}`, [github](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/access/server/config/passport.js#L13)? If so, in what circumstances can we use this "exports"?

---

Since authentication's authorization rules is written up in package "access" and used in package "mymodule", Mean.io packages are not independent of each other. The `Access` package is registered on

*myapp/packages/access/app.js*, [github](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/access/app.js):

```
var mean = require('meanio'),
  Module = mean.Module,
  passport = require('passport');

var Access = new Module('access');

Access.register(function(database) {

  // Register auth dependency

  var auth = require('./server/config/authorization');
  require('./server/config/passport')(passport);

  // This is for backwards compatibility
  mean.register('auth', function() {
    return auth;
  });

  mean.register('passport', function() {
    return passport;
  });

  Access.passport = passport;
  Access.middleware = auth;

  return Access;
});
```

**QUESTION B: Does Mean.io automatically link all the packages or is there code to link packages somewhere?** Is it linked due to the part with "This is for backwards compatibility" shown below? If so, where can "auth" be used? All the packages *myapp/packages/*? How about in the mean.io base app directory *myapp/*?

```
var auth = require('./server/config/authorization');

// This is for backwards compatibility
  mean.register('auth', function() {
    return auth;
  });
```

---

**QUESTION C: Why is it "Access.passport = passport;", but "middleware" for "Access.middleware = auth;"?** What what happen if it were "Access.auth = auth"?

Comment: As far as `exports` go, that is part of Node's module-system. Whenever you `require` something you'll get the `exports` object from the file you required.

Comment: For Question A, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it

Answer (score 1):

### REGARDING QUESTION A (on the use of `exports`)

In Node.js, assigning values to the `exports` object makes those values available to the code that `require`s the source file.

For example, given file `foo.js`:

```js
exports.foo = "FOO";
exports.bar = "BAR";
```

and file `main.js`:

```js
var foo = require('foo.js');
console.log('foo=',foo.foo,'; bar=',foo.bar);
```

running `node main.js` will output `foo= FOO ; bar= BAR`.

See, for example, [Node's module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) or [this write-up on `require` and `exports`](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/).

### REGARDING QUESTION B (on package "linking")

The answer to this question is the complement to the answer to Question A.

There is code to "link" the packages.  It is the `require` statement.

In your `app.js` source code, the first line (reading `var mean = require('meanio')`) will set the local variable `mean` to whatever values are assigned to `exports` object is when `meanio.js` and/or the `meanio` module is loaded.

Same with `passport = require('passport')`.  In that case, the local variable `passport` will be equal to the value of `exports` after [index.js in the passport module](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/index.js) is loaded.

### REGARDING QUESTION C

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking here, but let me take a stab at it.

In this case:

1) `var mean = require('meanio')` in line 1 "imports" the meanio module, such that the local variable `mean` is more or less set equal to the value of `exports` in the meanio module.

2) `Module = mean.Module` in line 2 sets the local variable `Module` equal to the value of `mean.Module`, which must have been assigned in the meanio module.

3) `var Access = new Module('access')` is instantiating an instance of the `Module` class, assigning it to the local variable `Access`.

4) `Access.passport = passport` assigns the instance variable named `passport` within the instance of `meanio.Module` named `Access` (to the value of the `passport` module `require`d on line #3)

5) `Access.middleware = auth` assigns the instance variable named `middleward` within the instance of `meanio.Module` named `Access` (to the value returned by `require('./server/config/authorization')` in line 11).

I'm not familiar with the "meanio" module, but based on this code it looks like you are configuring the `meanio.Module("access")` instance (named `Access`) by assigning specific "magic" variable names.

In other words, rather than `Access.passport = passport; Access.middleware = auth` you might have `Access.setPassport(passport); Access.setMiddleware(auth)` or (rather than line 5) `var Access = new Module('access',passport,auth)`.

That is, the author of the "meanio" module seems to have decided to use special variable names to configure the class rather than "setter" methods or parameters passed to the constructor.  I assume that somewhere in the meanio code you'll find a reference to something like `this.middleware` and `this.passport`, where the code is assuming you have "filled in" those instance variables as happens in the last few lines in your code sample.

If you were to add `Access.auth = auth` then all that would happen is that the `Access` object would have a new attributed named `auth` whose *value* is equal to the that of the local variable `auth`.

If you used `Access.auth` *instead* *of* `Access.middleware`,  I assume whatever code in the `Access` class that is using `this.middleware` will fail, since no value was ever assigned to `Access.middleware` and `Access.auth` is not one of the "magic" variable names that meanio is looking for.